# Styling a responsive notice message using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I'm trying to style a notice message. That is an alert image with a message, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7j6Qz/1/).
I would like it to be with a minimal amount of html, so currently the html for the notice is only

```
<p class="notice error">This is a message</p>
```

The jsfiddle does what I want, except that the parent can be of any size, meaning the html above should be responsive. Is it possible to position the icon so that in any situation it is just before the message ? And if this is not possible, other neat solutions are welcome too of course!

Thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the previous solution, just edited my answer

Use `:before` pseudo and it will do the job, this way you don't have to add an extra element in your HTML.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7j6Qz/11/)

```
p.notice:before {
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `img` to HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <p class="notice error"><img src="http://www.foghornnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Alert-Icon-.png" alt="warning" />This is a message</p>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
html,body,#parent{
    width:100%;
}

p img{
    height:20px; /* some height */
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7j6Qz/5/)

Comment: I guess you didn't got his question, resize the element in his demo, and see icon goes far away

Comment: In my fiddle the icon doesn't go.

Comment: Because you are using an `img` tag where op is using `background`

Comment: Yes, I said "Add `img` to HTML". This is an example without using the `background` property.